# Why isn't the re attribute listed when I do dir() on a match object in python?

Tags: python, regex, attributes

Here is some sample Python code:

```
import re
some_regex = re.compile(r"\s+1\s+")
result = some_regex.search(" 1 ")
dir(result)
```

I get back the following using Python 2.6.1:

```
 ['__copy__', '__deepcopy__', 'end', 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'span', 'start']
```

Yet `result.re` exists (from the interpreter):

```
>>> result.re
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x10041bc90>
```

How can an attribute not be listed when using the `dir()` function?

This page confirms the existence of the `re` attribute:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.re

Now I understand that if one tries to access an attribute which is not listed via `dir()`, then `__getattr__` is called, but I don't see `__getattr__` listed as one of the object's attributes either, so I'm left scratching my head.

**Update**

And here is proof of the existence of `matchobject.re` in the Python 2.6.1 documentation:
http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.1/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.re

Comment: If I run your example in 2.7.2, dir() does show re

Comment: Oh. How odd. So is this just a bug of 2.6.1?

Comment: @emiller: No, it's not a bug.  It behaves as documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see this behavior because the class is implemented in C, and in the same way that `dir()` is unreliable with a custom `__getattr__()`, it is also unreliable when the C code defines a getattr function.

Here is a link to the Python 2.6 C code for the SRE_Match getattr function:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f130ce67387d/Modules/_sre.c#l3565

Note that the methods defined in the `match_methods` array have Python implementations and are visible in the `dir()` output, but handled by an `if` in the `match_getattr()` function is not visible.

In Python 2.6, it looks like this includes the following attributes: lastindex, lastgroup, string, regs, re, pos, and endpos.

Here is a link to some of the Python 2.7 code which is slightly different.  Here there is not a getattr function implemented for SRE_Match, and all methods and attributes can be found in the `match_methods`, `match_members`, and `match_getset` arrays, and everything is visible in `dir()`.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/60a7b704de5c/Modules/_sre.c#l3612

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `dir()` is a convenience function and results in an approximate list of attributes.  From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir):

> Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

Note that it is impossible to always give a complete list of attributes, since classes can do in their `__getattr__()` and `__getattribute__()` methods whatever they want.

Comment: But wouldn't it make sense to list the existence of `__getattr()__` with `dir()` in the first place so one can tell something is up?

Comment: @emiller: The class in question is implemented in C, and the function in the [`tp_getattro` slot](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) of the type object does not necessarily have a Python wrapper.  For what it's worth, Python 2.7 *does* include `__getattribute__()` in the list, further illustrating the quoted passage from the documentation.